# Modifying TCP/UDP payload (RADIUS) using scapy

Tags: scapy, radius

How can I refer to a Radius attribute in the below packet in scapy? My intention is to capture packet and modify values in few attributes using scapy. I can modify Radius fields above the attribute list...

```
>>> org_pkt[1][Radius].show()
###[ RADIUS ]###
  code= Access-Challenge
  id= 5
  len= 109
  authenticator= f050649184625d36f14c9075b7a48b83
  \attributes\
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Framed-IP-Address
   |  len= 6
   |  value= 255.255.255.254
   |###[ Framed-MTU ]###
   |  type= Framed-MTU
   |  len= 6
   |  value= 576
   |###[ Service-Type ]###
   |  type= Service-Type
   |  len= 6
   |  value= Framed
   |###[ Radius Attribute ]###
   |  type= Reply-Message
   |  len= 11
   |  value= 'Hello, %u'
   |###[ EAP-Message ]###
   |  type= EAP-Message
   |  len= 24
   |  \value\
   |   |###[ EAP-MD5 ]###
   |   |  code= Request
   |   |  id= 1
   |   |  len= 22
   |   |  type= MD5-Challenge
   |   |  value_size= 16
   |   |  value= 266b0e9a58322f4d01ab25b35f879464
   |   |  optional_name= ''
   |###[ Message-Authenticator ]###
   |  type= Message-Authenticator
   |  len= 18
   |  value= 11b5043c8a288758173133a5e07434cf
   |###[ State ]###
   |  type= State
   |  len= 18
   |  value= c6d195032fdc30240f7313b231ef1d77

>>>
```

In the above example, I can modify

```
>>> org_pkt[1][Radius].id = 6
>>> org_pkt[1][Radius].id = 5
```

but not the values of attributes. Is it possible? If not please suggest another tool for easy modification of packet. I tried Wire-edit but the free version does not have Radius protocol.

Comment: What do you mean you can't modify it ? `org_pkt[1][Radius].attributes` is expected to work

Comment: Now I get the philosophy behind it. A list under attributes.
>>> org_pkt[1][Radius].attributes[1].value
576
>>> org_pkt[1][Radius].attributes[1].value = 1000
>>> org_pkt[1][Radius].attributes[1].value
1000
It works. Thanks a lot.